# Error trying to `#require "ctypes.foreign";;` in utop on Windows (Cygwin)

Tags: cygwin, ocaml, opam, libffi, utop

I managed to install and run *OCaml* + *OPAM* + *utop* on Windows (in Cygwin) thanks to the [awesome guide by Jonathan Protzenko](https://github.com/protz/ocaml-installer/wiki). In *utop*, I especially want to be able to use ***ctypes*** + ***ctypes.foreign*** to quickly experiment and prototype accessing various WinAPI calls. Theoretically, I managed to install the *ctypes* packages successfully (`opam install ...` succeeds). Unfortunately, when I try to actually load them ***in utop, they fail miserably*** with a surprising error message:

```
utop # #require "ctypes.foreign";;
Error: Reference to undefined global `Ctypes_closure_properties'
```

Trying to do the same in `rlwrap ocaml` gives a somewhat longer error message:

```
# #require "ctypes.foreign";;
C:\OCaml\lib\unix.cma: loaded
C:\OCaml\lib\bigarray.cma: loaded
C:\OCaml\lib\str.cma: loaded
C:\cygwin64\home\Mateusz\.opam\system\lib\bytes: added to search path
C:\cygwin64\home\Mateusz\.opam\system\lib\ctypes: added to search path
C:\cygwin64\home\Mateusz\.opam\system\lib\ctypes\ctypes.cma: loaded
C:\cygwin64\home\Mateusz\.opam\system\lib\ctypes\ctypes-foreign-base.cma: loaded
Cannot load required shared library dllctypes-foreign-base_stubs.
Reason: dllctypes-foreign-base_stubs.dll: Cannot resolve ffi_type_pointer.
C:\cygwin64\home\Mateusz\.opam\system\lib\ctypes\ctypes-foreign-unthreaded.cma: loaded
Characters -1--1:
  #require "ctypes.foreign";;

Error: Reference to undefined global `Ctypes_closure_properties'
```

*Note: [full transcript of the sessions is here](https://gist.github.com/akavel/a79998df8ea9520f8048b970f8a42975) — it contains output of a `utop` session in the cmd.exe terminal, and also of an additional `rlwrap ocaml` session in the Cygwin terminal.*

I have absolutely no idea why that happens, or how I could further try to debug/pinpoint/diagnose the situation, so that I could try to find some workaround. (And by the way — I'm a total newbie to OCaml & OPAM, although I'm reasonably experienced in C/C++ and Linux generally.) What follows are some questions I have, that I imagine might hopefully help nudge the problem enough to push me through the roadblock:

- Is there a way to tweak a git repo (i.e. ctypes) locally and pass it to OPAM instead of the original github one?
- I've managed to google up [some comment](http://lists.ocaml.org/pipermail/ctypes/2015-May/000178.html), which seems to mention that ["a static version of libffi" might work, as hinted also in ctypes issue #198](https://github.com/ocamllabs/ocaml-ctypes/issues/198#issuecomment-60273187); but I'm a total newbie to OCaml, and unfortunately I have no faintest idea how I could apply this suggestion to *utop*?
- How can I tell OPAM which libffi to use for ctypes? (specifically, to use "static libffi"?)
- How can I check if the *mingw64-x86_64-libffi* Cygwin package I do have installed is statically linked, or dynamically? or if both variants are provided, then which one is used by ctypes? I found some answers on SO regarding how to detect if a libffi.a is linked with PIC (?) relocations [`-fpic`?], but they all seemed really hackish and none of the ones I tried seemed really to work, at least in my case.
- Any at all help would be highly appreciated. I don't even know who to ask about this, given it's at a crossing of OCaml, OPAM, utop and Cygwin, all of those being huge and somewhat unrelated/orthogonal systems. I've tried [posting the issue on ctypes repo](https://github.com/ocamllabs/ocaml-ctypes/issues/435), but all it got over a month's time was a "patches-welcome" label.

Comment: For local tweaking you can do `opam pin add -kgit ctypes path/to/local/repo#master`

Comment: I think you might be able to tweak which libffi is being used by using the `LIBFFI_CFLAGS` and `LIBFFI_LIBS` environment variables. See this file https://github.com/ocamllabs/ocaml-ctypes/blob/master/src/discover/discover.ml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mingw64-x86_64-libffi ships with static and dynamic libraries, but the gnu linker will use the dynamic versions by default.

Patching the build of ctypes would be very fiddling (the build system of ctypes is rather complex, a mix of scripts and makefiles). So just try the following: delete the dynamic libraries (`/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/lib/libffi.dll.a` and `/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/bin/libffi-6.dll`), rebuild ctypes and then restore the deleted files.

### opam-repository-mingw

By the way: https://fdopen.github.io/opam-repository-mingw/installation/ contains a patched version of flexdll (https://github.com/alainfrisch/flexdll/pull/3 applied - the problem is not specific to libffi) that supports the dynamic and static versions of libffi. `opam install ctypes-foreign ctypes utop` should work out of the box, if `/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/bin` is in your PATH. Full step-by-step guide below:

1. Download a 64-bit [graphical installer](https://fdopen.github.io/opam-repository-mingw/installation/) and run it.
2. After installation completes, start the *"Cygwin64 Terminal"* (gets installed into *Cygwin* group in the *Start Menu*).
3. Type `cygwin-install gui` to start the *Cygwin Setup/Installer* and use it to install some text editor (*joe* or *nano* or *vim* or whatever you prefer).
4. Use the text editor you installed to edit your `~/.bashrc` file, add the following line:

   ```
   export PATH="/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/bin:$PATH"
   ```

   then execute it in your *Cygwin Terminal* (just type it in the terminal, or run the following command instead):

   ```
   $ source ~/.bashrc
   ```
5. Install *depext* which will auto-download any required OS level (native) dependencies for OPAM packages, the use it to install *ctypes* and *utop*:

   ```
   $ opam install depext depext-cygwinports
   $ opam depext -i ctypes-foreign ctypes utop
   ```
6. **Switch from *Cygwin Terminal* to *cmd.exe*,** for example by typing the following command in *Cygwin Terminal*:

   ```
   $ cmd /c start cmd
   ```
7. Start *utop* in *cmd.exe* terminal, and use it to call the [*MessageBox* WinAPI function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645505(v=vs.85).aspx) as a test that all's working well:

   ```
   c:> utop

   utop # #require "ctypes.foreign";;
   utop # let dll = Dl.dlopen ~filename:"user32.dll" ~flags:[];;
   val dll : Dl.library = <abstr>
   utop # open Ctypes;;
   utop # let mb =
     Foreign.foreign ~from:dll "MessageBoxA"
     (ptr void @-> string @-> string @-> uint @-> returning int) ;;
   val mb : unit Ctypes_static.ptr -> bytes -> bytes -> Unsigned.uint -> int =
     <fun>
   utop # mb null "hello" "world" Unsigned.UInt.zero;;
   - : int = 1
   utop # #quit;;

   c:>
   ```

   <sub>[NOTE: not all of the above *utop* commands may be required, but that's what worked for me.]</sub>

   [image: utop + ctypes.foreign + WinAPI = MessageBox]

Comment: Wow, thanks for the reply! I can't try it now yet, but regarding the *opam-repository-mingw* project: can I safely install it after I've already followed the protz's guide? i.e. in a "dirty" cygwin environment... Will maybe the graphical installer create a parallel cygwin env? if yes, do you possibly know where are the sources of the graphical installers available?

Comment: Yes, it's possible to use the graphical installer in order create a separate cygwin installation, e.g. `C:\foo` instead of `C:\cygwin`. Cygwin supports multiple independent installations. You only have to be careful with global Windows environment settings created by Protzenko's installer (It sets $OCAMLLIB and adds something to your $PATH, which could lead to unintended side effects) To play around, just add something like `export PATH=.....` to the `~/.bashrc` of your new cygwin installation (before the code added by opam). Installer sources: https://github.com/fdopen/opam-cygwin-installer

Comment: Removed `libffi.dll.a` and `libffi-6.dll` as you suggested, then did `opam uninstall ctypes-foreign ctypes`, then again `opam install ...`, but it still fails in utop with the same messages. As to fdopen's installer, it fails to install *conf-pkg-config* required by *ctypes* with `pkg-config: not found`. Don't know how to access cygwin setup here to try installing pkg-config. [Note: didn't try fixing $PATH. And $OCAMLLIB looks ok.]

Comment: depext/depext-cygwinports will install missing cygwin packages for you: `opam install depext depext-cygwinports && opam depext -i ctypes-foreign ctypes`

Comment: Woohoo, it worked (via fdopen's repo and depext), thanks! :) I managed to call [`MessageBox`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645505(v=vs.85).aspx) :) I'll try to edit your answer to update it with all the details of the steps I did.